# Pywinauto: How to set focus on a window from a dataframe

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate some windows tasks and I got a dataframe of all windows opens, and then I added some more coluns in order to make some validations before proceed with the automation.

Then I want to loop through all data in the column `WebBrowser` from the dataframe in order to set focus and activate this windows to the front, and then resize.

But I'm getting an error when I try the following command `app.set_focus()`: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_focus'`.

***Note: I don't know how to resize yet, I stopped in a step before, but if someone could give me a hint I'd appreciate it.***

My code:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop
import pandas as pd

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
window = [w.window_text() for w in windows]

# Create a dataframe in order to store the windows needed
df_windows = pd.DataFrame(window, columns =['WebBrowser'])
# Filter dataframe only to show all windows from Brave web browser
df_windows = df_windows.loc[df_windows['WebBrowser'].str.contains("Brave:", case=False)]
# Add column profile from Brave
df_windows['Profile'] = df_windows['WebBrowser'].str.split(':').str[1].str.strip()
# Add column window open from Brave
df_windows['Window'] = df_windows['WebBrowser'].str.split(':').str[0].str.strip()
# Add column about the website open from Brave
df_windows['Website'] = df_windows['Window'].str.replace(" - Brave", "").str.strip()
# Filter dataframe only to show all bombcrypto game window
df_windows = df_windows.loc[df_windows['Website'] == 'GuilhermeMatheus']

print(df_windows)

for x in df_windows['WebBrowser']:
    print(x)
    app = Desktop(backend="uia").windows(title=x)
    app.set_focus()
    # resize window after
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I run your code, I found your app in `app = Desktop(backend="uia").windows(title=x)` is a list. So you need to get the app element in list, that is, `app[0]`. Here is the fixed code and it will run correctly.

```
for x in df_windows['WebBrowser']:
    #get first element in list
    app = Desktop(backend="uia").windows(title=x)[0]
    app.set_focus()
```

And if you want resize windows, you can read article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460538/resizing-notepad-via-pywinauto)

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much.